# Undefined error when trying to map child objects in React

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, api, next.js

I'm trying to get image url for nested JSON object.

Tried `{post.image.url}` but I get an error saying **url undefined**

I appreciate any help or guidance that could be offered. New to Javascript / React but after an hour of Googling and searching couldn't come up with a solution for this. Must be missing something simple :-P

*Here's my code...*

```
export const getAllPosts = async () => {
    return await fetch(
        `https://notion-api.splitbee.io/v1/table/${NOTION_BLOG_ID}`
    ).then((res) => res.json());
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const posts = await getAllPosts()
    return {
        props: {
            posts
        },
    };
}
function Blog({ posts }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => (
                <Link href="/blog/[slug]" as={`/blog/${post.slug}`}>
                    <div>
                        <div className='text-6xl'>{post.title}</div>
                        <img className='w-24' src={post.imgUrl}></img>

                        
                        {/*{post.image.rawUrl}*/}

                    </div>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Blog
```

*Here's the JSON...*

```
[
{
"id": "90ee0723-aeb5-4d64-a970-332aa8f819f6",
"slug": "first-post",
"date": "2020-04-21",
"Related to Notion API Worker (Column)": [
"0976bfa6-392a-40b0-8415-94a006dba8d9"
],
"imgUrl": "https://www.notion.so/image/https:%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsecure.notion-static.com%2F689883de-2434-4be3-8179-a8ba62a7bc1e%2Fsnowmountain.jpg?table=block&id=90ee0723-aeb5-4d64-a970-332aa8f819f6&cache=v2",
"image": [
{
"name": "snowmountain.jpg",
"url": "https://www.notion.so/image/https:%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsecure.notion-static.com%2F689883de-2434-4be3-8179-a8ba62a7bc1e%2Fsnowmountain.jpg?table=block&id=90ee0723-aeb5-4d64-a970-332aa8f819f6&cache=v2",
"rawUrl": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/689883de-2434-4be3-8179-a8ba62a7bc1e/snowmountain.jpg"
}
],
"title": "My first blogpost bruce"
}
]
```

Comment: Can you try like, ```{post.image[0].url}``` .. As image is an array, I think you need to try ```[0]```to get the first element..

Comment: @codemonkey, That is related to Nextjs which will gets called by default on pre render page.. Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` property of a `post` is an array as denoted by the bracket on the end of line 1:

```
1. "image": [
2.   {
3.     "name": "snowmountain.jpg",
4.     "url": "https://www.notion.so/image/https:%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsecure.notion-static.com%2F689883de-2434-4be3-8179-a8ba62a7bc1e%2Fsnowmountain.jpg?table=block&id=90ee0723-aeb5-4d64-a970-332aa8f819f6&cache=v2",
5.     "rawUrl": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/689883de-2434-4be3-8179-a8ba62a7bc1e/snowmountain.jpg"
6.   }
7. ],
```

If you know that there will always be exactly one image you could access it directly by referencing the first array item.

```
function Blog({ posts }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => (
                <Link href="/blog/[slug]" as={`/blog/${post.slug}`}>
                    <div>
                        <div className='text-6xl'>{post.title}</div>
                        <img className='w-24' src={post.imgUrl}></img>

                        
                        {post.image && post.image[0].rawUrl}

                    </div>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that this could err if the array is `undefined` / `null` or if it's empty, so you should probably safe-guard it by only displaying something if it exists.

Comment: Yea got this error : `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` . Even when I tried                         `{post.image[0].name !== undefined ? 'yes' : null}`
or `{post.image[0].rawUrl === undefined ? 'yes' : 'no'}`

Comment: Solved it: `{post.image && post.image[0].rawUrl}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `then()` method, if you use `async\await`.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

> await can be put in front of any async promise-based function to pause
> your code on that line until the promise fulfills, then return the
> resulting value.

```
export const getAllPosts = async () => {
    return await fetch(
        `https://notion-api.splitbee.io/v1/table/${NOTION_BLOG_ID}`
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const posts = await getAllPosts()
    return {
        props: {
            posts
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: When I tried that I got errors saying the data wasn't formatted to JSON correctly?

Comment: @BrucevanZyl could you show results of `console.log(posts)`  in method `getStaticProps()`?